# jQuery .toggle() to show and hide a sub-menu

Tags: jquery, toggle

I'm trying to use show/hide on a submenu. It looks like this:

1. Parent 1
2. Parent 2

   1. Child A
   2. Child B
3. Parent 3

   1. Child C
   2. Child D

I only want to show the submenu when I click on its parent. Currently, whenever I click on any parent, I get all of the submenus.

Like so:  http://jsfiddle.net/saltcod/z7Zgw/

Also, clicking on a link in the submenu toggles the menu back up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
//select all the `<li>` element that are children of the `.parent` element
$('.parent').children().click(function(){
    
    //now find the `.child` elements that are direct children of the clicked `<li>` and toggle it into or out-of-view
    $(this).children('.child').slideToggle('slow');     
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/z7Zgw/1/

Basically the code above uses `this` to reference the clicked `<li>` element so we can find the `.child` element that is a child of the clicked `<li>` element.

This:  `$('.child')`

Changed to: `$(this).children('.child')`

### Update

Also you can stop the propagation of the `click` event on the nested `.child` elements like this:

```
$('.parent').children().click(function(){
    $(this).children('.child').slideToggle('slow');

//select all the `.child` elements and stop the propagation of click events on the elements
}).children('.child').click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/z7Zgw/9/

Docs:

- `event.stopPropagation()`: http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation
- `.children()`: http://api.jquery.com/children

Comment: Best answer. Thank you ❤️

Answer (score 2):

Your code was:

```
$('.parent li').click(function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.child').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

`$('.child')` selects all the "children". Change it to `$('.child', this)`, to select only the ones inside the current element.

The `click` event bubbles, so in order to ensure that only clicking the parent itself toggles the state, you can compare the `event.target` with `this`.

However, this is quicker:

```
$('.parent > li > a').click(function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().find('.child').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z7Zgw/6/)

**EDIT** as @Jasper pointed out, this is shorter/quicker:

```
$('.parent > li > a').click(function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).siblings('.child').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Comment: `.parent().find('.child')` could also be `.siblings('.child')` or a faster selector would be `.next()` since the `.child` elements appear to come directly after the `a` elements.

Comment: You're right, of course. I changed the script twice (once for each problem the OP asked about), and missed that.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. I went with the .siblings() approach. Short, simple and to the point. Plus, I thought the odds of me remembering stopPropagation() the next time were pretty slim =).    Thanks a lot.