# jQuery Parent & Children for SlideToggle

Tags: jquery

I have built a CSS Menu for a shopping site. The idea is the main category gets clicked then the slideToggle kicks in and loads the subcategories. I have the principles built and was looking at jQuery .children

However when I am clicking the link, Nothing is happening.

My jQuery is as follows :

```
$('ul.sub_menu').css('display','none');

$(".nav-list li a.clickable").toggle(function () {
  $(this).children().slideToggle();
}, function() {
  $(this).children().slideToggle();
}
```

My HTML Structure Goes Like This...

```
<ul class="nav nav-list">
  <li>

    <a class="clickable" href="#">Christmas</a>

    <ul class="sub_menu">
      <li>
        <a href="/~sweetdis/category/wreaths" >Wreaths</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/~sweetdis/category/large-logs">Large Logs</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </li>
</ul>
```

Am I just missing something here?

Many Thanks

Comment: Consider putting it in jsfiddle for easier help

Comment: Check following url for slideToggle in jquery.

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469807/jquery-toggle-to-show-and-hide-a-sub-menu][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469807/jquery-toggle-to-show-and-hide-a-sub-menu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

```
$('.sub_menu').hide();
$('.clickable').click(function(){
    $(this).next('ul').slideToggle();
});
```

Or -

```
$('.ulClass li a:first').click(function(){
    $(this).next('ul').slideToggle();
});
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7LZUL/)

Nothing is happening when you click on `clickable` because it doesn't have any children

Comment: Thats great, so .next was the way forward not children. Many Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Because you use `slideToggle` for the children of the `anchor` with class `clickable` when there is no children of this anchor exist, you can use [**`siblings`**](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) instead:

```
$('ul.sub_menu').css('display','none');

$(".nav-list li a.clickable").click(function () {
    $(this).siblings('ul.sub_menu').slideToggle();
});​
```

**FIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/QqMks/