# Convert bootstrap navigation to wordpress

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, wordpress-theming

Hello guys I made bootstrap menu that is a little bit more complexed and I want to convert it to Wordpress. I have my main menu in the middle, logo on the left, and on the right I have search bar and dropdown menu. I read a lot on this subject but nothing I tried worked.
This is my HTML code for nav:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <hr class="blueLine">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>      
            </button>   
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>">
                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/fresiusLogo.png">
            </a>  
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse navbar-center collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
                <li class=""><a href="enternal.html">Enternal <br> Nutrition</a></li>  
                <li class=""><a href="indi.html">INDI <br> Partnership</a></li>  
                <li class=""><a href="parental.html">Parental <br> Nutrition</a></li>  
            </ul>
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 pull-right">
                <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
                        <div class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>                        
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <span>Fresenius Kabi Globa</span>
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Select Website
                    <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="https://www.google.com/">Test 1</a></li>
                      <li><a href="https://www.google.com/">Test 2</a></li>
                      <li><a href="https://www.google.com/">Test 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </div>
        </div>      
    </div>  
</div>
```

I have tried following instructions I found online but none worked for me I have also tried using wp-bootstrap-navwalker, but could not implement it with my code. One of my issues is for example when I click on my dropdown menu it doesn't do anything cause I'm targeting # is there anyway to target # with php ? Does anyone have any idea how to convert this to Worpress ?

Comment: It's very clear what you are asking for. Perhaps you could include links to the tutorials you've tried( one or two ), and a link to an example page running your code.

Comment: @PhillHealey I actually got it to work using some JQ and wp-bootstrap-navwalker. Meybe I should delete this post.

Comment: No, you should post your answer below and then come back and mark it as accepted in 2 days. This way other people can learn from your issue and solution.

Comment: @PhillHealey Thx I have done it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I got this to work using JQuery and wp_bootstrap_navwalker.php
This is how my code looks now:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <hr class="blueLine">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>      
            </button>   
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>">
                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/fresiusLogo.png">
            </a>  
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse navbar-center collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
                 <?php
                    wp_nav_menu( array(
                        'menu'              => 'primary',
                        'theme_location'    => 'primary',
                        'depth'             => 2,
                        'container'         => 'div',
                        'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
                        'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
                        'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
                        'fallback_cb'       => 'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker::fallback',
                        'walker'            => new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker())
                    );
                ?>  
            </ul>
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 pull-right">
                <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
                        <div class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>                        
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <span>Fresenius Kabi Globa</span>
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Select Website
                    <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
                      <li><a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">Test 1</a></li>
                      <li><a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">Test 2</a></li>
                      <li><a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">Test 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </div>
        </div>      
    </div>  
</div>
```

Also you need to use JQuery to make dropdown work. I suggest reading these two posts: 
[jQuery .toggle() to show and hide a sub-menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469807/jquery-toggle-to-show-and-hide-a-sub-menu/9469857#9469857) 
[Wordpress drop-down-menu open on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15899922/wordpress-drop-down-menu-open-on-click)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `walker` class to set your bootstrap menu. You need to attach `wp_bootstrap_navwalker.php` file inside `function.php` or you can add code directly.

You can download the file or copy code from [here](https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker/blob/master/wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php).

Just use this file and then call walker class from wp_nav_menu function like this:

```
<?php
    wp_nav_menu( array(
      'menu' => 'top_menu',
      'depth' => 2,
      'container' => false,
      'menu_class' => 'nav',
      //Process nav menu using our custom nav walker
      'walker' => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
    );
?>
```

You can follow [this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-integrate-a-bootstrap-navbar-into-a-wordpress-theme--wp-33410) link to understand this concept in depth.

Thanks.