# jQuery .toggle() to show and hide a sub sub-menu

Tags: jquery, toggle, hide, show

I'm using this question's code to make a show/hide toggle

[jQuery .toggle() to show and hide a sub-menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469807/jquery-toggle-to-show-and-hide-a-sub-menu)

```
$('#menu-lateral .sub-menu').hide(); //Hide children by default

$('#menu-lateral > li > a').click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).siblings('.sub-menu').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

The problem is that my sub-menu has its own sub-menu with many items. Is there a way to adapt this code to work ALSO in the next level?

**Important info: wordpress makes by default the child UL with the same class, so both are .sub-menu.**

Like:

```
<ul id="menu-lateral" class="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-29"><a href="#">Parent Level 1</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-108"><a href="#">Parent Level 2</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li id="menu-item-104"><a href="#">Element</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qfygM/1/

Thanks for the help!

**UPDATE: The solution may be found here >> http://jsfiddle.net/qfygM/7/**

Made by Zenith.

```
$('#menu-lateral .sub-menu').hide(); //Hide children by default

$('#menu-lateral li a').click(function(event){
if ($(this).next('ul.sub-menu').children().length !== 0) {     
    event.preventDefault();
}
$(this).siblings('.sub-menu').slideToggle('slow');});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, in this case you could just use the descendant selector -  `$('#menu-lateral li a')` as your selector  as opposed to the direct child selector you're currently using - `$('#menu-lateral > li > a')`.

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/qfygM/2/)

As you're now using the descendant selector, all future descending 'levels' will be targeted individually in your  `$(this).siblings('.sub-menu').slideToggle('slow');` statement, making it very easily extendable.

Comment: Now the problem is that the sub sub-menus are unclickable.

I researched and the problem is with the event.preventDefault();

Is there a way to enable it just in the buttons that DON'T have children?

I can add different classes to parents and children if that's needed.

Thanks for the attention.

Comment: I mean that the "element" in here http://jsfiddle.net/qfygM/2/ doesn't link to the page anymore. I click and it's not redirected to the URL.

Comment: @tibelchior if $(this).next('ul.sub-menu').children().length !== 0 then preventDefault.

Comment: Sorry to disturb you, but I really can't make it work. Could you fiddle it? http://jsfiddle.net/qfygM/2/

Comment: worked! I'll edit the question to add your solution so others can find it. Thanks

Comment: Zenith, do you know why isn't this code working with Firefox and IE? Try the fiddle in those browsers. Works perfectly in Chrome and Safari. http://jsfiddle.net/qfygM/6/

Comment: @tibelchior http://jsfiddle.net/qfygM/7/. event isn't a global object in FF/IE (I forgot about that for a moment) :D

Comment: A simple word... can't believe how perfect everything must be. Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 0):

One alternative would be to use $el.toggleClass(hideClass) ( or $el.addClass(hideClass) & $el.removeClass(hideClass) ) on the elements.

Then define the .hideClass {display: none} in your stylesheet.

I don't think this can be used in conjunction with toggle() though, so you'd have to stick with this method of hiding/displaying element.