# jQuery toggle open li when clicking on closed li

Tags: jquery, toggle

I've been working and searching on this for hours but my approach doesn't work.

This is my situation:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sqeq/DqV9b/1/)

If I click on one of the two "submenu-ebene1" they toggle. But when I click on the other one, I want the one that is currently open to close again. The same behaviour for Link 1 and Link 2 inside.

IMHO all I need to do is to search the siblings of my submenu-ebene1 li for the one that currently has the class ".active" and slideToggle that. Nearly the same for submenu-ebene2 due to different markup there.

I tried to do it like this:

```
//toggle submenu-ebene1
$("submenu-ebene1").on("click", function() {
    $(this).siblings(".active").slideToggle();
});

//toggle submenu-ebene2
$("submenu-ebene2 li").on("click", function() {
    $(this).siblings(".active-ebene2").slideToggle();
});
```

I would love to get some tips first instead of a solution - I'm here to learn and it drives me crazy to not understand that simple toggle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Like this** http://jsfiddle.net/SyYzY/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/aN5ey/

- Might help: [jQuery .toggle() to show and hide a sub sub-menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17556553/jquery-toggle-to-show-and-hide-a-sub-sub-menu)

Hope it fits your need `:)`

**Code**

```
//apply active-classes to submenu-ebene1
$(".link").click(function () {
    $(".submenu-ebene2").slideUp();
    $(".active").toggleClass("inactive active");
    $(this).addClass("active").removeClass("inactive");
});

//apply active-classes to submenu-ebene2
$(".submenu-ebene2 > li.inactive-ebene2").click(function (e) {
    $(".active-ebene2").toggleClass("inactive-ebene2 active-ebene2");
    $(this).addClass("active-ebene2").removeClass("inactive-ebene2");
});

// submenu-ebene1 toggle
$(".submenu li").click(function (e) {
    $(this).next("li").children(".submenu-ebene2").slideToggle();
});

// submenu-ebene2 toggle
$(".submenu-ebene2 li").click(function () {
    $(this).next("li").children(".submenu-ebene3").slideToggle();
});




//toggle submenu-ebene1
$("submenu-ebene1").on("click", function () {
    $(this).siblings(".active").slideToggle();
});

//toggle submenu-ebene2
$("submenu-ebene2 li").on("click", function () {
    $(this).siblings(".active-ebene2").slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: Hey Tats_innit, thanks so far. It works for submenu-ebene1 but not for Link 1 and Link 2 inside. Could you please explain what I did wrong and why you chose children instead of siblings?

Comment: @Sqe glad it helped `:)` yep, I reckon the whole script could be re-written, let me see I will try and fix the link issue for you as well 2 mins `:)`

Comment: okay, thanks. I just realized that if you click multiple times on submenu-link1 now it always slides up and down again. Could be because of my horrible script...

Comment: @sqe here you go this might fit your need `:)` **demo** http://jsfiddle.net/HgjQ9/ to make your code bit concise check tyhos out and borrow some ideas to your existing codebase: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17556553/jquery-toggle-to-show-and-hide-a-sub-sub-menu

Comment: Thank you but I'm afraid both of your solutions are not working. When you click twice on the same submenu-ebene1, it slides up and down again. When you click once on Link 1/2, the submenu-ebene3 toggles and is hidden forever but I just wanted to toggle submenu-ebene1 and 2. These seem to be the same problems I had hehe. Weird stuff...

Comment: Yes, that took me a step further! I completed my tasks with adding an additional class for submenu-ebene3 in order to not hide them with the first jquery .link function. Thank you very much!! http://jsfiddle.net/sqeq/aN5ey/1/

Comment: @sqe Awesome! `:)` glad it helped, and I reckon latter try and refactor the code as well, I have added one of the old SO link to play around with `.sibling` API. +1 to you as well!